# Laravel Excel Download using Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, export, laravel-excel

So I created a PHP Controller to handle exporting data which is posted by JS. The problem is I can see it creates something in the console but the file download never starts. I tried using ->store (laravel excel) and keeping it in an export folder but again when I try to use

```
return \Response::download($result);
```

it still won't start the download. The problem I'm having is just **getting the download to start.**

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.exportMatrix = function () {
    var postData = {list: $scope.list, matrix: $scope.matrix};
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/export',
        dataType: 'obj',
        data: postData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log("failed");
    });
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/export', 'ExportController@export');
```

**PHP Controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use Excel;
use Response;
class ExportController extends Controller {

public function export()
{

    $excel = App::make('excel');

    Excel::create('Test', function($excel) {
        $excel->setTitle('new awesome title');

        $excel->sheet('Sheet', function($sheet) {
            $sheet->fromArray(array(
                array('data1', 'data2'),
                array('data3', 'data4')
            ));
        });


    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `download('xlsx')` not `export`?

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried download('xlsx') as well as export
This throws out a bunch of 
�QĿi!��K�y3�J<���
from my JS controller 
    success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
which is obviously formatting for the file but the download doesn't initialize.

Comment: Ok so I'm pretty sure it's because I'm sending the response back to javascript controller and the download then needs to be initiated by the JS (example using new Blob([data], {type: 'application/xls'});)
So I suppose my followup question is how to create an effective export controller using laravel/excel and angular data. Because it seems to be complicating things so much more than they need to be. I want to send angular data to an export controller and use laravel excel to create and download it.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having a same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I used [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to download the blob it sent back so just load up FileSaver and use it saveAs(blob).

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/api/v1/download',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
       data:data
   },
   responseType: 'arraybuffer',
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data) {
   var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});

   saveAs(blob, title + ".xlsx");
}).error(function (data) {
   console.log("failed");
});
```

I made sure to use

> responseType: arraybuffer

and saveAs type:

> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Because reasons.

Comment: the responsetype really help me

Answer (score -4):

Route::get('/export', 'ExportController@export');