# Laravel Excel download not working

Tags: php, laravel, download, axios, laravel-excel

The problem is the same as described here [Laravel Excel Download using Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808416/laravel-excel-download-using-controller)

But I just can not believe that there is no method to deal with Excel downloads in Laravel without using another resource. I was already able handle the instant downloads in controller with `response()` for PDFs.

Mabybe the headers are wrong? My code:

```
public function getFile($file) {
    $path = storage_path('app/excel/exports/' . $file);

    $headers = array('Content-Type' => File::mimeType($path));

    return response()->download($path, $file, $headers);
}
```

So the excel file is created and saved correctly in my storage folder (happens before the code above). Then I use an `axios.get` method to download the file with the function above.

Headers I am getting:

> Accept-Ranges:bytes
>   Cache-Control:public
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="test_file.xlsx"
>   Content-Length:7066
>   Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

But whatever I do or try to change the download just won't start.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to solve it.

It seems to be not possible to solve this with a simple `axios.get` request to the route. Instead I needed to open the route directly with a link.

Did not work with:

HTML
    `<button @click="downloadExcel()">Download Table as Excel File</button>`

```
downloadExcel() {
    axios.get('/customers/export');
}
```

Simple solution (instead of just using `axios.get`):

```
<a :href="/customers/export"><button>Download Table as Excel File</button></a>
```

So it would also be possible to open the route after the axios request with:

```
downloadExcel() {
    let newWindow = window.open();
    axios.get('/customers/export')
       .then(response => {
         newWindow.location = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/customers/export';
       });
}
```

Comment: How can I do it with authorisation header

Answer (score 1):

You can try with these two headers.

```
return response()->download($path, $file, [
     'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
     'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='Report.xls'"
]);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it is not downloading automatically.
Even if I response with a blob and try to download it with https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ a file then gets downloaded but is corrupted.

Comment: Okay, let me check and let you know same.